# SQL prepared statement throwing an error about syntax

Tags: java, mysql, sql

So I am using SQL with phpMyAdmin. Now I want to make an update to my database with a prepared statement but doind it gives me the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'autor='Lol' WHERE id=44' at line 1
```

And this is how my statement looks like:

```
command = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE books SET name=? author=? WHERE id=?");
command.setString(1, name.getText());
command.setString(2, author.getText());
command.setInt(3, IDx);
command.execute();
```

Wat is wrong with the statement I have made? It should be working In my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a comma before `author`

```
UPDATE books 
SET name = ?, author = ?
WHERE id = ?
```

Comment: Thanks! How careless of me too overlook it !

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate the updated fields in a comma like:

```
 command = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE books SET name=?, author=? WHERE id=?");
```